# why two spam policy apply on the same email

Tags: exchange, spam, outlook, spam-filter

Recently, we made some Spam setting as below shown, but don't know why the result is, emails are prepended with 'spam' and move to junk mailbox at the same time. We want SCL 5 emails is prepended with 'spam' but only SCL 7~9 emails are moved to junk mailbox. Anyone know how to do that. Anyone can provide some troubleshooting subjection? Thanks a lot[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I44FH.png)

Answer (score 0):

In my research, it may be related to mailbox option “block or allow” – “Automatically filter junk email”. You could check the configuration.

And about your requirement, here is [a similar discussion](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/office-365-spam-issues-scl-365-or-outlook/7d7a6eda-741f-4e0f-bda9-32f0c504f6be?page=2), however, it seems not simple to do this. According the link, have a try to select “Don’t move mail to junk mail folder”, and create a rule to see if it could work.

Comment: it just makes no sense, if you select "Don’t move mail to junk mail folder”, all spam will go to inbox.